# How to get a Miglayout cell to span vertically down all rows

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, miglayout

I have a Miglayout set up as such.

```java
setLayout(new MigLayout("hidemode 3","[200]" +"[50]" +"[400]",
                                    "[]" +
                                    "[]" +
                                    "[]" +
                                    "[]" +
                                    "[]" +
                                    "[]" +
                                    "[]"));
```

In the rightmost (third) column I want it to span down all seven rows. As if it were one merged cell going the whole vertical length of the layout. Spanning horizontally seems to work fine, but I can't get or find a command to make it span vertically.

This is how I have that element in code:

`add(myRightColumn, "cell 2 0");`

but I've also tried adding `,span` and `,spany` and listing the series of cell/row numbers in the string argument. All with no luck.

What is the correct syntax for what I want to do?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it. The correct way to do this is like so

```java
add(myRightColumn, "cell 2 0, span 1 7");
```

meaning it should span 1 column and 7 rows.